# AppStoreConnect - Developer action needed status won't go away

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

So we've submitted first version of our app with over 60 iAPs, but it got rejected because of the bug. When we resubmitted a new bundle, iAP section in "Prepare for submission" page was not available anymore, and iAPs were in "Developer action needed" state.

All the iAPs have "Rejected" on default English localization row. When I change something there and save, it change to "Prepare for submission", but state of the iAP is still the same.

I've also asked app review team **twice** in review notes to review our iAPs. Twice new versions have passed the review but iAPs are still the same, and they're not working in the app at all, products are just not showing.

Please help, any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this in the future and struggling - there's no obvious way to solve this. It is (yet another) bug in App Store Connect.
We had another app that was rejected after first submission, but after resubmitting iAPs changed to "Approved" and worked. But not for this one though.

Had to submit a ticket to support, in the end they manually pushed iAPs and subscription to "In review", and after that they were approved. It was done without resubmitting another binary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).